# bash to loop through seperate directory run a command in another and re-direct output

Tags: bash, loops

I am trying to create a `bash` that will use all the bam files stored on a separate drive (/media/cmccabe/C2F8EFBFF8EFAFB9/pool_I_090215), run them in a program that I have changed the directory to, and the output gets re-directed to (/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/pool_I_090215).  I'm not sure if the below is close but hopefully its a start. Thank you :)

```
cmccabe@HPZ640:~/Desktop/NGS$ for f in /media/cmccabe/C2F8EFBFF8EFAFB9/pool_I_090215/*.bam do bname=`basename $f` pref=${bname%%.bam} samtools view -H $f | sed '/^@PG/d' | samtools reheader - $f > /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/pool_I_090215/${prefix}_newheader.bam done
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax of the for loop requires the `do` be preceded by a newline or semicolon:

```
for f in /media/cmccabe/C2F8EFBFF8EFAFB9/pool_I_090215/*.bam ; do
    bname=`basename $f`
    pref=${bname%%.bam}
    samtools view -H $f | sed '/^@PG/d' | samtools reheader - $f > /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/pool_I_090215/${prefix}_newheader.bam
done
```

Also note that `$pref` and `$prefix` are different variables. If the paths might contain weird characters, it would be safer to double quote the variables.